# Different definitions of limit point

Tags: real-analysis

I am learning measure theory and integration from the E.Stein, R.Shakarchi book. However, I ran into the definition of limit point. And this definition is totally different from the Rudin's book from which I learned analysis.

**Definition 1 (Stein-Shakarchi):** A point $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a limit point of the set $E$ if for every $r>0$, the ball $B_r(x)\cap E\neq\varnothing$.

**Definition 2 (Rudin):** A point $x\in \mathbb{R}^d$ is a limit point of the set $E$ if for every $r>0$, the ball $B'_r(x)\cap E\neq\varnothing$, where $B'_r(x)=B_r(x)-\{x\}$.

It's easy to see that Definition 2 $\Rightarrow$ Definition 1. However, the converse is not true, consider the example $E=[1,2]\cup \{3\}.$

Why I am asking this question because for long time I was always using the Definition 2 and the Definition 1 seems to weird.

Why many authors use different definitions for limit point of a set? What is the motivation?

Would be very grateful for help.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @md2perpe, edited

Comment: @RFZ See also [Philosophical reason behind definition of limit point](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1746041/philosophical-reason-behind-definition-of-limit-point).